# how to get pre-defined value of variable inside function code in PHP wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

So I have these:

```
echo ('timeframe1:');echo ($timeframe);

function filter_where($where = '') {
echo ('timeframe2:');echo ($timeframe);
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$timeframe days")) . "'";
return $where;
}

echo ('timeframe3:');echo ($timeframe);
```

Result from those codes above are:

```
timeframe1: 5
timeframe2:
timeframe3: 5
```

Question is, how to get my $timeframe value inside the function? As you can see, the result from echoing the $timeframe inside the function is null. How get the predefined $timeframe value of 5 inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

use `GLOBAL` to pass variable that is outside of a function

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
global $timeframe; // <---- pass it as global
echo ('timeframe2:');echo ($timeframe);
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$timeframe days")) . "'";
return $where;
}
```

OR You call pass `$timeframe` as a parameter to your function

```
function filter_where($where = '', $timeframe ) /* here we pass a variable into function */ {
echo ('timeframe2:');echo ($timeframe);
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$timeframe days")) . "'";
return $where;
}
```

call function:

```
filter_where('', $timeframe);
```

it's not that clean as variant with `GLOBAL`, but still work though.

Comment: it returned a warning: Warning: Missing argument 2 for filter_where() in

Comment: how to pass the second argument?